# Trying to make an event depend on another event and data is passed along using jquery custom events

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, publish-subscribe

for this problem I want to pass along data depending if a checkbox is checked. the data comes from the .on() second paramater.

I want to do something like this. I know it is really messed up. Im not sure how the data work and when to use .trigger()

```
 $(document).on('justData', function(e, data){
    console.log(data);
 })
$('.justData').on('click', function(){
    var insert
    dataobj ={
        "mike" : 'mikevalue',
        "john" : 'johnValue'
    }
    $("#checkThis").on('change', function(e, data){
        if(this.checked){
            insert = dataobj.mike
        }else{
            insert = dataobj.john
        }
    })

    $(this).trigger('justData', insert)
})
```

I wanted to insert "mikevalue" if the box is checked and "johnvalue" if unchecked.

I'm learning how to use mediators. I think that's when you do $emitter = $({}) so I want to separate event. when the user clicks on the $(.justData) i would have $({}).trigger("Ischecked") something like that I'm confused. If some one can show me how to pass along dynamic data to different events using $emitter .trigger() .on() that would be great.

Comment: The on change event is being attached every time a click event happens on `.justData` which I'm assuming is undesired behavior.  I've removed this in the answer.

Comment: do you mind accepting this answer by pressing the checkmark above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. This is the simple and clear example given from the [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for handling custom events:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

Also cleaned up your code a little bit:

```
$('body').on('justData', function(e, data){
   console.log(data);
});

$('.justData').on('click', function(e){
   var insert = "",
       $checkbox = $('#checkThis'),
       data = {
       "mike" : 'mikevalue',
       "john" : 'johnValue'
   };
   if($checkbox.prop('checked')){
       insert = data.mike;
   } else {
       insert = data.john;
   }
   $('body').trigger('justData', insert);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you do me a big a favor. can you make this so that it works when the user clicks on $(.justData) p element or whatever it checks if   checkbox is checked to insert data. right now. if the checkbox is checked it outputs. I want it to be if $(.justData) is **clicked**  then checks if checkbox is checked than insert the proper data using custom events for decoupling . If you do that I will accept this answer.

Comment: made changes - will likely be clearer if you add in some html to help explain what you are trying to accomplish.